# Issues with Test-Path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to enumerate Windows (admin) shares remotely and then `Test-Path` against each share to verify whether a folder is present.
The issue is `Test-Path` returns "True" only if the account running the `powershell.exe` has permissions to view the folder in question.
Thus I am trying to open a new `powershell.exe` and run the script in the context of a user who has permissions.

```
#share enumeration and Test-Path
$scriptBlock = {
    Param ([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$cred)
    $shares = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName COMPUTER -Credential $cred
    $sharename = $shares.Name
    $sharename #shares are correctly enumerated
    foreach ($name in $sharename) {
        $name1 = '\\COMPUTER' + $name + '\FOLDER'
        $name1 #UNC location is correctly set e.g. \\COMPUTER\d$\FOLDER
        $path = Test-Path -Path $name1
        Write-Host $path #always returns FALSE
    }
}

$username = "user"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command & {$scriptBlock}  $cred"
```

The `Start-Process` command does not correctly receive the credentials stored in `$cred`, but rather asks for credentials. Even if correct credentials are provided, the output of `Test-Path` returns FALSE for all shares.
`powershell.exe` runs in the context of the current user.
If I add the current user as Administrator of the remote machine, `Test-Path` returns TRUE for the location containing "\FOLDER".
This scenario is not what I am trying to achieve as we will be running this script remotely through a framework.

Comment: Have you tried the `-Credential` parameter of `Test-Path`?

Comment: `"-noexit -command & {$scriptBlock}  $cred"` mangles `$cred` into a string. Meaning you're effectively passing "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" into the scriptblock.

Comment: You just don't need to run a 2nd PowerShell process.

Comment: Invoke-Command might be a better option as it has a parameter for credentials

Comment: the `$Creds` variable needs to have a parameter for it to be bound to. that parameter is `-Credential`. [*grin*] the location you used makes the cmdlet try to assign `$Creds` to the argument list ... so you are - as usual - STRONGLY recommended to use the full parameter names. plus, in this case, you likely otta put the argument list stuff _last_ so there is less chance of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don' t use plain text passwords in scripts, especially when using admin creds. You are exposing yourself and your org to unnecessary risks.

If you don't want to be prompted for creds during a script run, then you need to store them, in advance, in a secure way and call from there. There are lots of articles all over the web about securing credential in PowerShell scripts, using,  Windows Credential Manager, Secure XML files, or even the registry.

This...

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command & {$scriptBlock}  $cred"
```

... is not valid syntax. Should be this ...

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command & {$scriptBlock}" -Credential $Cred
```

[Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) - it does have a credential property.

Lastly, if you are running this from your workstation, and you have perms to do this, then why are you passing creds at all? 
Your interactive logon, if you are logged on with an account that has perms on the target, it will just work and you would not need the Start-Process at all.

For example, just doing this ...

```
# share enumeration and Test-Path
# Using variable squeezing to assign and output variable, debug validation effort

# $scriptBlock = {
    # Pick a random AD computer and show all shares
    "`n***"
    "*** List all share data  ***"
    "***`n"
    ($shares = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -Filter '*').Name[7])

    # Process test validation
    "`n***"
    "*** Testing share path ***"
    "***`n"
    foreach ($share in $shares) 
    { ($sharename = "\\$($share.PSComputerName)\$($share.Name)") + ' : ' + ($path = Test-Path -Path $sharename)}
# }
```

Would get you this ...

```
# Results

***
*** List all share data  ***
***


Name        Path                                   Description                                            
----        ----                                   -----------                                            
ADMIN$      C:\Windows                             Remote Admin
C$          C:\                                    Default share
install     C:\install                                       
IPC$                                               Remote IPC
print$      C:\Windows\system32\spool\drivers      Printer Drivers

***
*** Testing share path ***
***

\\LabServer01\ADMIN$ : True
\\LabServer01\C$ : True
\\LabServer01\install : True
\\LabServer01\IPC$ : False
\\LabServer01\print$ : True
```

Now if your logged on creds did not have perm, then, yes, pass them ...

```
($cred = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME")
```

... in the Start-Process, or even better [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command), if PSRemoting is enabled.

```
($cred = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME")

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $((Get-ADComputer -Filter '*').Name[7]) -ScriptBlock {
    # Pick a random AD computer and show all shares
    "`n***"
    "*** List all share data on $env:COMPUTERNAME  ***"
    "***`n"
    ($shares = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME)

    # Process test validation
    "`n***"
    "*** Testing share path ***"
    "***`n" 
    $shares | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Testing $($PSItem.Name) : "  -NoNewline
        Try {Test-Path -Path $PSItem.Path}
        Catch{"Path for $($PSItem) is empty"}
    }
} -Credential $cred


# Results

***
*** List all share data on LabServer01  ***
***


Name       Path                                      Description        PSComputerName                           
----       ----                                      -----------        --------------                           
ADMIN$     C:\Windows                                Remote Admin       LabServer01                                 
C$         C:\                                       Default share      LabServer01                                 
install    C:\install                                                   LabServer01  
IPC$                                                 Remote IPC         LabServer01                                 
print$     C:\Windows\system32\spool\drivers         Printer Drivers    LabServer01                                 

***
*** Testing share path ***
***

Testing ADMIN$ : True
Testing C$ : True
Testing install : True
Testing IPC$ : Path for Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string. is empty
Testing print$ : True
```

Comment: ello,

Thank you all for your valuable input.

We will not be storing the credentials in the script body. We will be using a framework which encrypts the credentials and pass them securely to the script ;)

- using Test-Path with the -Credentials param produces an error "Test-Path : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The FileSystem provider supports credentials only
on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials."

Comment: Regarding the Start-Process functionality, it works if you remember that if one is to run a program in the context of another user, this user should be present on the local system as well.
So adding a local user with the same username/pass as the privileged remote user does the trick.
This was supposed to be a very easy task which grew as an ugly abomination of a hack - I am rethinking the whole design now.

Thank you once again you all have a lovely week!